# How can I return the value of a custom form field

Tags: javascript, json

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://sdk.paylike.io/3.js"></script>
<script>
    var paylike = Paylike('***');
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', pay);

    function pay(){
        paylike.popup({
            // locale: 'da',  // pin popup to a locale
            title: 'Product',
            description: '<?php echo $amount; ?>',
            currency: 'GBP',
            amount: <?php echo $price; ?>,
            // saved on transaction for retrieval from dashboard or API
            custom: {
                // arrays are fine
                products: [
                    // nested objects will do
                ],
            },
            // data from fields will be merged with custom
            fields: [
                // elaborate custom field
            {
                    name: 'name',
                    type: 'name',
                    placeholder: 'John Doe',
                    required: true,
                },

                {
                    name: 'email',
                    type: 'email',
                    placeholder: 'john@example.com',
                    required: true,
                },

                {
                    name: 'address',
                    type: 'address',
                placeholder: 'Address',
                    required: true,
                },
                {
                    name: 'postcode',
                    type: 'postcode',
                    placeholder: 'Postcode',

                    required: true,
                },

            ],
        }, function( err, res ){
            if (err)
                return console.log(err);
            console.log(res);



              location.href = 'success.php?e=' + email;
        });
    }
</script>
```

I want to be able to get the email submitted in this pop form so I can attach it to the success URL and thus send an email receipt. However, my attempt at doing this does not seem to be working.

Here is the output from the console:

```
Object
custom: Object
address: "116"
email: "test@gmail.com"
name: "John Doe"
postcode: "E9 7SR"
transaction: Object
id: "581b23717cb2057463e8d76a"
```

How do I return the email object?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't see where you defined your email variable

Comment: @EvanMosseri how do I define it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
res.custom.email
```

Which translates into:

```
location.href = 'success.php?e=' + res.custom.email;
```

I think you should probably escape that value using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). Emails might not be a problem to URLs, but I would consider it a good habit:

```
location.href = 'success.php?e=' + encodeURIComponent(res.custom.email);
```

Next time you have a similar problem, try putting `debugger;` (breakpoint) in your code (in this example right after `}, function( err, res ){`), launch the developer tools in Google Chrome, reload, and then the script will run but stop at the breakpoint allowing you to inspect variables and their values at that exact point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Paylike JS library you're using, but it seems like you have it in your `res` object: expect something such as `res.email`, `res.fields.email` or something like that.

If you look at the console.log you're getting from the `console.log(res);` command with Google Chrome (which allows you to browse into console-logged objects) you should be able to see where it is.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question with the result of the console. Please have a look